# Print first page only using vb.net when printing word doc

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
Dim objWordApp As New word.Application
            Dim objDoc As word.Document
            objWordApp.Documents.Open("c:\integra-billing\final\" + wordfilename, False, True)
            objWordApp.Visible = False
            objDoc = objWordApp.ActiveDocument

            objWordApp.DisplayAlerts = word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
            'now print the word document
            objWordApp.PrintOut()

            'now close it
            objWordApp.Documents.Close(word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
            objWordApp.Quit()
            objWordApp = Nothing
```

that opens, prints and closes a word document

how can i make this only print the first page of the word document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9f0ke7y.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

See the VB example for printing the current page, which will be the first page when the document is just opened.